# how to collect IIS log through logstash and display it on Kibana?

Tags: logstash-forwarder

We'd like to collect IIS log through logstash and display it on Kibana based on [this doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/5.4/advanced-pipeline.html) , any advice would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kibana alone is just a UI. What you need is an ELK stack.

You need Elasticsearch, Kibana and Logstash.

Logstash is the software that takes IIS logs and forward it to elasticsearch in order to make them visible in Kibana.